# jQuery detect scroll of screen and add In static HTML

Tags: jquery, scroll, detection

I have some code that detects when you scroll which then calls a function.

In this function I want to be able to fade in content as you scroll. So as I reach the bottom of the page it calls a function then snippets of static html is then faded in, say 10 rows of content at a time.

Hopefully someone can help me finish this off as im stuck: -

http://jsfiddle.net/sTSxS/

Thanks

Comment: Hi Paul. Here's a link to one of the scripts that I wrote for a project at work which may help you. The goal was to take a side-nav pane and use jQuery to fade in/out a pre-determined number of links in the list when the visitor clicked view more/view less. You will have to modify it to work for your purposes and to fire on scroll, but it may help point you in the right direction. It is compatible with IE 6-10. Let me know if you have any questions, and good luck! :) http://development.zacharykniebel.com/incremental-accordion/incremental-accordion.txt

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to give you the link to the page that shows how it is initialized and how the events can be set up (I did not write the events into the plugin, in order to make it more customizable). Here you go: http://development.zacharykniebel.com/incremental-accordion/incremental-accordion-events.txt

Comment: thanks for that, think that is over my head though, im only just learning this. Just was after something simple, where in that function  it would load 10 rows at a time fading in, then show a loading gif icon, not sure how i would do this, maybe a loop and time interval function?

Comment: I'm going to post an answer with and outline of what you'll need so that we don't have too many long comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so first you'll probably want to have some sort of proportion to determine how many rows you want to fade in. Why do you need this proportion? If the user only scrolls down an inch, you don't want to fade in 6 inches of content.

*I would like to make a note here and point out that in your final implementation, a proportion IS NOT what you want to use. Although it is a simple way of thinking about the solution, in reality you are going to want to fade in an amount of content relative to your page's location and the content size. Furthermore you are going to want the content to fade in, even if the entire row isn't visible to the visitor (I can help you with this later, if need be).*

For our purposes, let's say that each row is 20px in height, with no space in between rows, and our ratio is 1 row fades in per every 20px scrolled (Note that with this proportion, your content won't fade in until you have scrolled it completely into view).

The next step is to design a way to track how much you are scrolling by. To keep it simple, let's just use a variable to hold the current window position (this variable will be updated after every 20px scrolled):

```
var current = $(window).scrollTop(); //sets the initial value
```

Next you will want to create a way of keeping track of how many rows you have faded in. There are many ways of doing this (Some better than the one I am going to use), but I am going to use a variable for sake of simplicity.

```
var rowsShown = 0;
```

Next you need to write your scroll-event handler to call your code to determine if you should and, if so, fade in your rows:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    ...code to determine if you should and actually fade in rows...
});
```

Now you need to write your conditional to determine if you should fade in any rows. You start by writing another variable to determine the new window position and compare that with the previous position, as stored in `current`. Remember that our proportion was 20px per row, so the window must have scrolled by at least 20px to fade in another row:

```
var newPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

if ((newPosition - current) >= 20) {
    ...fade in rows...
    current += 20; //update current
}
```

*I would like to point out that, for our purposes in this simple "tutorial" you will want to set current to be 20 more than it previously was, NOT update it to the new current position (`newPosition`). Why, you ask? Because mice don't always scroll one pixel at a time (in fact, they hardly ever do) so, as we are keeping it simple with 20px per row faded in, we want to maintain that proportion by keeping current a multiple of 20. When it comes time to write your final version of this, you will likely want to change it to `current = newPosition;` however.*

Next, you will have to write your fade in code:

```
$(rowsToFadeIn).eq(rowsShown).fadeIn(speed, function () {
    rowsShown += 1; //increment the accumulator
    ...do any other call back stuff here...
});
```

Lastly, you will want to write a similar method for scrolling up and fading out your content (otherwise if you scroll up and start scrolling down again you wont see your content fading it - it will fade ahead of you).

Please note that this is not the complete implementation - this is just to get you started. And get something for you to test and play with. Once you have it working, I would modify the effect part of the script to use `.promise().done()` in order to determine when the previous effect has completed. If you are uncomfortable using a `.promise().done()` then I would do the following:

1. Create a variable `var fading = 0` to hold the number of elements you are currently fading.
2. each time you are about to start fading an element you will do the following:

   1. Add one to `fading`
   2. Call your effect via a call similar to this:

      `$(rowsToFade).eq(rowsShown).delay((fading - 1) * speed).fadeIn(.....`

      - a delay of `(fading - 1) * speed` waits for all currently running fades (not including the one you are about to run)
   3. In the callback of your `.fadeIn()` method, subtract one from fading (`fading -= 1;`) in order to prevent unnecessary delays.

I would try to avoid timers if I were you. They have a fair amount of overhead and they never do exactly what you want. Plus, using them things like fades tends to produce choppy    effects, especially in slow browsers and occasionally in faster browsers like Chrome.

Let me know if you have any questions on this. I'm happy to help. Good luck! :)

EDIT: I almost forgot, you are going to have to set the body or a wrapper element's height to be what the height would be if your elements were part of the normal flow, as `display: none` (which is required for `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`) will remove them from the flow and shorten your page to the height it would be without them there. This could potentially cause you to not even have a scroll bar.

EDIT 2: Please also note that you can (and should if you use it) improve the suggested updated implementation using `.delay()` as you will undoubtedly encounter unwanted delays. It is basically plan B if you don't like plan A (`.promise().done()`) ;)

You will, however, likely learn more from improving B than from using A, if you are new to jQuery.

Comment: Do you know where i might be going wrong with this: http://jsfiddle.net/sTSxS/2/ im struggling to be honest - only just learning it. I managed to get the additional rows showing when I added just the fade in code within the getTableItems() function, but nothing else, sorry to be a pain mate

Comment: Hi Paul. This should give you a good head-start: http://jsfiddle.net/Cjk4m/23/ It needs the reverse function for scrolling up and it has to be tailored to fit your specifications, but it should be a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ( $(document).height() / 1.2 ) && document.documentElement.scrollHeight != document.documentElement.clientHeight ) {
                doit();

}
```